# Hypervelocity stars sucked in a black hole

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, black-holes, astrophysics, orbital-motion, stars

As one of the stars spirals in toward the black hole, its companion is flung outward at a tremendous velocity. But why is the second star flung outward?

Comment: What do you know about circular motion?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Image Source: [Expelled Stars](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/hubble/science/expelled-star.html)

This image above is an illlustration of a three star system, all bound by gravity, but with two stars orbiting each other. One of the orbiting pair is significantly more massive than the other. As they approach the Black Hole, the loosely bound third star is dragged inwards by the strong gravitational field of the Black Hole. But before this occurs, its momentum is passed to the two (further away from the black hole) orbiting stars.  If the conditions are right, this momentum is transferred to provide sufficient escape velocity for the orbiting pair.  The evolution timescale of a star is proportional to it's mass. Given enough time, the more massive star may become a red giant, and if the orbital distance is small enough, the stars will merge, becoming a [Blue Straggler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_straggler).

A binary star system can follow the same pattern, as regards momentum transfer, allowing the other star to achieve very high velocities.

Comment: So do you mean to say that when one star gets pulled into the black hole, its momentum gets transferred to the other star which gets escape velocity?

Comment: Not **all** of its momentum, (that is my fault, sorry), but if you look at diagram two, you will see a complicated path, as the "doomed" star will spiral in, over time, rather than go straight in, since the BH is rotating and an accretion disc forms around it. Split the circular orbital motion of the two stars into components. As the nearer star gets pulled in, it moves faster, pulling the second star around in its orbit faster, but giving it enough tangential velocity to continue in its curved path, away from  the BH at a much greater speed.